# .NET Maui - prevent tab navigation if there's unsaved data or condition

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

How to prevent my application from switching tabs if a certain condition is not met in .NET Maui?

I need to verifiy a condition before tab navigates to the clicked tab. If the condition is not met, then stop the navigation.

Below is my Tab bar xaml code along with the on property changed C# code. I cannot get the

```
GetDeferral();
```

from my C# code

```
    private void WorkOrderTabBar_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TabBar listener && listener.CurrentItem?.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
        {
           //listener
            var navigation = listener.CurrentItem.Navigation;
            var pages = navigation.NavigationStack;

            for (var i = pages.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                navigation.RemovePage(pages[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    <TabBar x:Name="Demo"
            PropertyChanged="WorkOrderTabBar_PropertyChanged"
            Route="Demo"
            >
        <Tab
     Title="Report Info"
     AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsTab"
     Icon="reportinfo.png"
     Route="WorkOrdersDetailsTab">
            <ShellContent
         Title="Work Orders Details Page Content Shell"
         AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsPageShellContent"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WorkOrderDetailsPage}" />

        </Tab>
        <Tab
     Title="Report Info1"
     AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsTab1"
     Icon="reportinfo1.png"
     Route="WorkOrdersDetailsTab">
            <ShellContent
         Title="Work Orders Details Page Content Shell"
         AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsPageShellContent"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WorkOrderDetailsPage1}" />

        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the App Shell XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="dap111.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dap111"  
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"> <!--put in your namespace-->

    <TabBar x:Name="Demo"
            Route="Demo"
            >
        <Tab IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled1}"
      Title="Report Info"
     AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsTab"
     Icon="reportinfo.png"
     Route="WorkOrdersDetailsTab">
            <ShellContent
         Title="Work Orders Details Page Content Shell"
         AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsPageShellContent"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WorkOrderDetailsPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled2}"
     Title="Report Info1"
     AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsTab1"
     Icon="reportinfo1.png"
     Route="WorkOrdersDetailsTab">
            <ShellContent
         Title="Work Orders Details Page Content Shell"
         AutomationId="WorkOrdersDetailsPageShellContent"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WorkOrderDetailsPage1}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

This is the App Shell code behind:

```
namespace dap111; //put in your namespace

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    ShellViewModel shellVm;

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = shellVm = new ShellViewModel();
        shellVm.IsEnabled1 = true;
        shellVm.IsEnabled2 = true;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);

        if (args.Source == ShellNavigationSource.ShellSectionChanged)
        {
            var aCondition = true;
            if (aCondition)
            {
                shellVm.IsEnabled1 = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace dap111  //put in your namespace
{
    public class ShellViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool _IsEnabled1;
        public bool IsEnabled1
        {
            get => _IsEnabled1;
            set
            {
                if (_IsEnabled1 != value)
                {
                    _IsEnabled1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(); // reports this property
                }
            }
        }

        public bool _IsEnabled2;
        public bool IsEnabled2
        {
            get => _IsEnabled2;
            set
            {
                if (_IsEnabled2 != value)
                {
                    _IsEnabled2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(); // reports this property
                }
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working. The on navigating method is not being invoked at all when i switch tabs.

Comment: Are you using a shell?

Comment: Yes i use shell

Comment: You should use a combination of mine and the other answer.  Your on navigating method should work.  Break the problem into smaller tasks.  E.g. create a new MAUI app - you will figure out why the navigating method does not work as it should.

Comment: I am using Android.  I would need to find out if this works in iOS.

Comment: I will update my question with the complete code for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the AppShell's OnNavigating method to cancel the navigating.

```
    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);

        if (args.Source == ShellNavigationSource.ShellSectionChanged)
        {
            if (Any Condition)
            {
             args.Cancel();// this will stop the navigation
             //and you can get the current page and target page by
             //args.Target.Location.OriginalString target
             //args.Current.Location.OriginalString current
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution is not working. The on navigating method is not being invoked at all when i switch tabs.

Comment: Did you test is on the windows? This is an known issue: [Shell does not always raise Navigating event on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12500). So it seems there is no way can stop the navigation on the windows after user switch the tabs. You may need to go back after the naigation completed manually by setting `Shell.Current.CurrentItem`. @Subhi